# Two animations on one layer

Tags: ios, calayer, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I have a CALayer,  and I want to show it and then hide.

```
CALayer *layerOne = [CALayer layer];
[layerOne addSublayer:textOne];
layerOne.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[layerOne setMasksToBounds:YES];
layerOne.opacity = 0.0;

CABasicAnimation *animationOne = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[animationOne setDuration:0];
[animationOne setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[animationOne setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[animationOne setBeginTime:3];
[animationOne setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animationOne setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[layerOne addAnimation:animationOne forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

This code work successfully,  layerOne appear after 3 seconds.

But I want to hide this layer, so I add this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animationTwo = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[animationTwo setDuration:0];
[animationTwo setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[animationTwo setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[animationTwo setBeginTime:6];
[animationTwo setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animationTwo setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[layerOne addAnimation:animationTwo forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

And it doesn't work.  layerOne not appear after 3 seconds. Its just flashed in second 6 and disappear.  Its seems like the second animation blocking the first one and only the second animation is going on.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Well, for one thing since the second animation has the same key, when you add it to the layer, the original animation will be removed.  When the animation is removed, it's long-term effect (setting opacity = 1.0) will also be removed so the animation will be immediately hidden.

For something like this, the normal process to show the layer is:

```
// set the final result you want to persist forever
layerOne.opacity = 1.0;

// set up your animation here
CABasicAnimation *animationOne = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animationOne.fromValue = @(0.);
animationOne.toValue = @(1.);
animationOne.duration = 3.;
animationOne.beginTime = 0.;
animationOne.removedOnCompletion = true;
animationOne.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemove;    // for clarity, this is the default
[layerOne addAnimation:animationOne forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

And then when you want to hide the layer just reverse the process:

```
// Set the final animation state
layerOne.opacity = 0.0;

// set up your animation here
CABasicAnimation *animationTwo = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animationTwo.fromValue = @(1.);
animationTwo.toValue = @(0.);
animationTwo.duration = 3.;
animationTwo.beginTime = 0.;
animationTwo.removedOnCompletion = true;
animationTwo.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemove;    // for clarity, this is the default
[layerOne addAnimation:animationTwo forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

If you're wanting to run the whole process as a single event, you should put both animations into a single animation group:

```
// set up your animation here
CABasicAnimation *animationOne = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animationOne.fromValue = @(0.);
animationOne.toValue = @(1.);
animationOne.duration = 3.;
animationOne.beginTime = 0.;
animationOne.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

// set up your animation here
CABasicAnimation *animationTwo = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
animationTwo.fromValue = @(1.);
animationTwo.toValue = @(0.);
animationTwo.beginTime = 6.;
animationTwo.duration = 3.;
animationOne.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

// set up the animation group
CAAnimationGroup*   group = [CAAnimationGroup new];
group.beginTime = 0.;
group.duration = 9.;
group.animations = @[ animationOne, animationTwo ];

[layerOne addAnimation:group forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

Comment: Thank you!   I try another method, using only one animation without making a group. I just set animationOne.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemove,  and set duration to 3, begin time to 3. fromValue =1 , toValue = 1.  This one animation on the second 3 set to 1 opacity of the layer, keep it 3 seconds and remove . So the opacity on the 6 second back to the 0.  Of course there is no fade in/out effects, but i don't need them.